# How to make grid style of specific width?

Tags: html, css

I have problem in making grid styling of specific width. I want to set the size of width as half the width of body. I have tried it but it consumes almost the full width of page. I want to decrease its width. Can anyone please tell me that how to decrease the width of grid
Here is the code which I have tried.

```
enter code here
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style>



    .floating-box {
        display:inline-block;
        width: 50px;
        height: 75px;
        margin: 10px;
        border: 3px solid #8AC007;
    }
</style>


</head>
<body>
<div class="floating-box">Grid Box</div>
<div class="floating-box">Grid Box</div>
<div class="floating-box">Grid Box</div>
<div class="floating-box">Grid Box</div>
<div class="floating-box">Grid box</div>
<div class="floating-box">Grid box</div>
<div class="floating-box">Grid box</div>
<div class="floating-box">Grid box</div>

</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4gzkx53q/1/

Comment: Your question is not clear. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Will there always be 8 grid boxes?

Comment: I want to show divs in grid style. Grid should be of specific width

Comment: No, you can increase @Jacques Marais

Comment: I want to set the width of Grid as half the width of body

Comment: if i understood correct, you can envelop the div cells into main div grid and give it the width you want, like https://jsfiddle.net/4gzkx53q/3/

Comment: Thank you @Emad Khalil. I just wanted that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok check this one, I think its cleaner code,
envelop the div cells into main div grid and give it the width, also you can remove the classes in each div and use the parent class to apply the style to all its child divs

```
.grid div
```

as in the example:

https://jsfiddle.net/4gzkx53q/5/